# Explanation of tuple notation in code snippet

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This a code snippet for peak element search in 2D array

```
(subStartR, subNumR) = (0, problem.numRow)
(subStartC1, subNumC1) = (0, mid)
(subStartC2, subNumC2) = (mid + 1, problem.numCol - (mid + 1))

subproblems = []
subproblems.append((subStartR, subStartC1, subNumR, subNumC1))
subproblems.append((subStartR, subStartC2, subNumR, subNumC2))
```

What is the need for parentheses in the first assignments and why are they used when appending to a list?

Comment: you are appending tuple to your list and that's it

Answer (score 4):

the `append` function adds only a single element to a list.  `extend` is what to use for multiple elements.

So what is happening is at each step, subproblems is having a "tuple" added to the end of it.  The inner () denote the tuple.  Add a `print subproblems` at the end and you'll get something of the form

```
[(.,.,.,.), (.,.,.,.)]
```

that is, a list of 2 tuples, each containing 4 elements.

The `(a,b) = (c,d)` is equivalent to `a=c`, `b=d`.

Answer (score 2):

Statements like:

```
(subStartR, subNumR) = (0, problem.numRow)
```

are packing two values into a tuple on the RHS of the `=`, and unpacking them into two variables on the LHS.  The parentheses are redundant -- just code

```
subStartR, subNumR = 0, problem.numRow
```

and you'll have the same effect with less punctuation noise:-)

In

```
subproblems.append((subStartR, subStartC1, subNumR, subNumC1))
```

the situation is very different.  The outside parentheses indicate the call to `append`; the inside ones group four values into one tuple, and they **are** necessary -- if you removed them, leaving just the outside ones, you'd actually be calling `append` with four arguments, which is not correct.

It's unfortunate that some punctuation characters (such as commas and parentheses) are overloaded with a few separate meanings, but, there just aren't enough distinct characters in ASCII to assign them differently!-)